# How to design a Cloud Firestore database schema

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Migrating from realtime database to cloud firestore needs a total redesign of the database. For this I created an example with some main design decisions.
See picture and the database design in the spreadsheet below.
My two questions are:

1 - when I have a one to many relation is it also an option to store information as an array within the document? See line 8 in database design.

2 - Should I include only a reference, or duplicate all information in the one to many relation. See line 38 in the database model.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KtzSwR67-6TQ3V9X73HGsI2EQDG9FA8WMN9CCHKq48/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Question 1 there's a solution in the firestore docs:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/arrays

instead of using an array you use a map of values and set them to 'true' which allows you to query for them, like so:

```
teachers: {
        "teacherid1": true,
        "teacherid2": true,
        "teacherid3": true
    }
```

And for Question 2, you just need to save the teacher-ids because if you have those you can easily query for the corresponding data.

Comment: This is outdated. Firestore now supports array-contains (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). A map like this will also run into the 20k indexed keys limit per collection. With more than 20,000 teachers, you will not be able to query this anymore.

Answer (score 15):

In general: keep the data store as shallow as possible, i.e., avoid subcollections and nesting.

Data can be related one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many. Firestore is an [automatically indexed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview) realtime datastore. Firestore is often subscribed to rather than just a one time query/response (the realtime nature of the system).

Regarding the Firestore data model, always consider *How will I query this data store?*. Use subcollections, arrays, and maps sparingly (rarely) and only if you must (and you most likely don't need to).  Use auto-id's vs human readable id's, e.g. use `000kztLDGafF4uKb8Cal` rather than `banana` for document ID's.

As app functionality increases, server-side scripting with Cloud Functions for Firebase and/or the Admin SDK becomes an invaluable tool for managing (creating and indexing) many-to-many data relationships. For example, full-text search is not supported in Firestore. This boils down to what seems like a barrier to implementing robust search functionality on your app.

In conclusion, try and avoid subcollections, nesting, arrays, and maps. Follow the keep it simple stupid, KISS, principle. Once your app scales up and/or requires more functionality, server-side scripting can be utilized to to keep your app responsive (fast) while offering robust features.

Comment: "keep the data store as shallow as possible" - I'm wondering if you have any references to unveil this point?

Comment: experience only. Indexing (server or cloud side/pre-filtering) enables the building of virtual tables - at least that a way to think about it. I've literally loaded 1.5 million documents into a single collection and once my primary query types are indexed, it's just as fast/responsive as if I had built out a dedicated collection. Shallow datastore means easier coding. 9 times out of 10, you don't need another collection. [KISS Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Thanks Ron. That makes a lot of sense. A quick question: what are the biggest disadvantages you can see with this approach? Also I guess you have something like "type" field in each document to maintain that "virtual table" approach so you can use it to fetch the documents that belong to the same "table", is that correct? Thanks again!

Comment: that's right, i use `type` and `category` or whatever. My top level collections are `users`, `locations`, `ratings`, etc. I set an `owner` property on these to enable authorization/security via the security rules.